# SimpleDateFormat parsing date differently on some android devices

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am parsing the date as:

```
public class Consts{
public static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATTER_WITHOUT_TIME_ZONE = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
public static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMATTER_2 = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ");
}

        cDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        sDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        eDate = new GregorianCalendar();

        if (mStartTimeTV.getText().toString().equals("Now")) {
            sDate.setTime(cDate.getTime());
        } else {
            sDate.setTime(Consts.DATE_FORMATTER_WITHOUT_TIME_ZONE
                    .parse(mStartTimeTV.getText().toString()));
        }

        if (!mEndTimeTV.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            eDate.setTime(Consts.DATE_FORMATTER_WITHOUT_TIME_ZONE
                    .parse(mEndTimeTV.getText().toString()));
        } else {
            eDate.setTime(sDate.getTime());
            // eDate = sDate;
        }
```

And then i format the date as below before sending it to the server.:

```
request.addProperty("StartTime",
                        Consts.DATE_FORMATTER_2.format(sDate.getTime()));
                request.addProperty("EndTime",
                        Consts.DATE_FORMATTER_2.format(eDate.getTime()));
```

But the thing is that on devices running 4.1.2 it is sending the date as:

`Start Date: 03-23-2015 21:17:20 +0500 
End Date : 10-23-2015 21:15:00 +0500`

which throws exception on the server side.

But on the other devices it is sending dates as:

`Start Date: 03-23-2015 21:12:13 GMT+05:00 
End Date : 03-23-2015 21:16:00 GMT+05:00`

which is required.

Am i doing something wrong? How can i prevent this problem so that all devices sends the same dates. (for example `03-23-2015 21:16:00 GMT+05:00`)

Comment: I am not seeing [an issue for this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=zzzz). Can you confirm that you get the same behavior on the emulator? Or is this from devices from some manufacturer?

Comment: I have tried it with Geny motion emulator running 4.1.1 and it is working fine. It has problems with Samsung and HTC running 4.1.2.

Comment: Try the official Android SDK emulator. While Genymotion should mirror it, since it too is based off of the AOSP, the official emulator would be a better compatibility test. If this is only happening on those devices, you may need to either see if the server can support a different timezone encoding, or perhaps switch to something other than `SimpleDateFormat` (e.g., Joda Time).

Comment: You should **ALWAYS** use joda-time instead of the JDK calendar/date mess

Comment: Can you guys please tell me that how can i format the date as: `03-23-2015 21:16:00 GMT+05:00`, i have tried `DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER_2 = DateTimeFormat
   .forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");` and `DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER_2 = DateTimeFormat
   .forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz")` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is caused by different locales set up on devices.

To mitigate the locale differences, you should use particular locale while formatting the date string. Here is a sample from my code, solving the same issue:

```
new SimpleDateFormat(C.FORMAT_DATETIMEZ, Locale.US).format(new Date(time))
```

Comment: Actually the thing is that we want to send dates to server with locale with them, then the server will store the dates after converting them to UTC/GMT and when we will get data from the server with dates we will again format it according to device locale.

Comment: send Locale separately

Answer (score 0):

You can extend SimpleDateFormat and override its format(...) function as following:

```
public class ExSimpleDateFormat extends SimpleDateFormat{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8275126788734707527L;

    public ExSimpleDateFormat() {

        super();
    }

    public ExSimpleDateFormat(String string, Locale us) {

        super(string, us);
    }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, java.text.FieldPosition pos)
    {            
        final StringBuffer buf = super.format(date, toAppendTo, pos);
        buf.insert(buf.length() - 2, ':');
        return buf;
    };
}
```

And execute following code:

```
Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();       
ca.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
ExSimpleDateFormat exSimpleDateFormat = new ExSimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z", Locale.US);
exSimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(ca.getTimeZone()); //your device timezone which can be GMT+xx:yy or GMT-xx:yy
String desiredTime = exSimpleDateFormat.format(ca.getTime());
```

**Output would be like: 23-03-2015 23:12:52 GMT+05:00**

Let me know if it helps.
Thanks