# trying to parse/formate date with timezone using joda-time/java

Tags: java, android, date, jodatime

I am trying to parse the date to look like `03-23-2015 21:16:00 GMT+05:00` using joda-time but i am not able to achieve it, however it is working fine with `SimpleDateFormat` but for some reason i want to use Joda-Time ([see my question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215748/simpledateformat-parsing-date-differently-on-some-android-devices/29217575#29217575))

Please note that i don't want to hardcode timezone to `GMT+05:00` but i want to set the user's default timezone.

I am trying it as:

```
public class Consts{

    public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER_2 = DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER_TEMP_1 = DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

}
```

And then i am using these formatters as:

```
        cDate = new LocalDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
        sDate = new LocalDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
        eDate = new LocalDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault());

        if (mStartTimeTV.getText().toString().equals("Now")) {
            sDate = cDate;
        } else {
            sDate = Consts.DATE_FORMATTER_WITHOUT_TIME_ZONE
                    .parseLocalDateTime(mStartTimeTV.getText().toString());
        }

        if (!mEndTimeTV.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            eDate = Consts.DATE_FORMATTER_WITHOUT_TIME_ZONE
                    .parseLocalDateTime(mEndTimeTV.getText().toString());
        } else {
            eDate = sDate;
        }
```

And while sending the dates to the server i am formatting them as:

```
        String s0 = Consts.DATE_FORMATTER_2.print(sDate);
        String s = Consts.DATE_FORMATTER_2.withZone(
                DateTimeZone.getDefault()).print(sDate);
        String s1 = Consts.DATE_FORMATTER_TEMP_1.print(sDate);
```

But the output is always: `03-24-2015 16:07:23`

I have also tried with `ZZZZ` but no luck.

Comment: You don't have a timezone on `LocalDateTime`. What if you use something like `DateTime` that actually has a zone on it?

Comment: @AndyTurner i had tried with `DateTime` too but let me double check again.

Comment: Yes @AndyTurner `DateTime` was required instead of `LocalDateTime`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LocalDateTime` doesn't have a time zone, so there is nothing to format. You should use `DateTime` instead, which you can obtain using [`LocalDateTime.toDateTime(timeZone)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#toDateTime(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)).