# While formatting GMT time to GMT+01:00 an extra hour is being added

Tags: java, locale, jodatime, simpledateformat

I am facing the problem of an hour being added to the time after formating only in GMT+01:00.

Here is how i am doing it:

```
private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");                       

    try {
        // Change Start date according to the Locale time
        formattor.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        date1 = formattor.parse("2015-03-26 11:17:41");
        formattor.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        String start = formattor.format(date1);

        // Change End date according to the Locale time
        formattor.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        date1 = formattor.parse("2015-03-26 13:17:00");
        formattor.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        String end = formattor.format(date1);

        System.out.println(start + " - " + end);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

```
2015-03-26 12:17:41 - 2015-03-26 14:17:00
```

I am facing the same problem with Joda-Time.

I have tested it with `GMT+01:00, West Africa Standard Time`

Comment: That's quite expected: If it's 11:17:41 in GMT, it's 12:17:41 in GMT+1. That's what GMT+1 means. What would you expect this to output and why?

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?  11:17 in GMT is the same time as 12:17 in GMT+01:00.  Why aren't you expecting this?

Comment: Looks fine. Include the TZ offset in the output which should help "visualize" the problem. The output time *should* be +1 from the GMT input.

Comment: Sorry i think i need to update the question.

Comment: or delete it.  There is no question here.

Comment: @DavidWallace actually while sending dates to the server i am sending it as: `StartTime=03-28-2015 10:50:56 WAT` and `EndTime=03-28-2015 11:50:00 WAT` but i think that server can only deal with GMT, i.e, the time should be sent as `GMT+01:00` instead of `GMT`. I am parsing the date as `DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER_2 = DateTimeFormat
   .forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");` before sending it to the server. Now the real question should be that what should i specify in pattern to get the GMT+01:00 instead of WAT. I have also tried `zzzz` in that case it prints complete name.

Comment: In case of `SimpleDateFormat`, `zzzz` give `GMT+01:00` format but i don't want to use `SimpleDateFormat`, see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29215748/1773155

Answer (score 0):

That's very obvious since your getDefault () would make the Timezone to GMT+01:00 hence you're seeing the same. Reframe the question if this is not what you're expecting.